# 1-dim subspace & sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm reading a book about algebraic topology recently and I have read through this sentence.
"The space of of all one dimensional subspace is equal to the one dimensional circle (that's the circumference)" I don't understand this but there isn't a lot further explanation about this. Can anyone explain to me why it is like this? THANK YOU!~

Comment: Do you mean the one-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Yes. Space of all 1 dimensional subspaces of ℝ².

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one dimensional subspaces are just the straight lines through the origin in $\mathbb R^n$

Each line through the origin is identified by a pair of antipodal points on the sphere $S^{n-1}$, the points being the points of intersection of the line with the sphere.

This correspondence is a one-one correspondence.

In $\mathbb R^2$, they are just the pairs of antipodal points in $S^1$.

Now the one dimensional spaces have been identified with antipodal pairs of points in $S^1$. The latter is quite easily seen to be homeomorphic to $S^1$ itself.

Comment: Why "The latter is quite easily seen to be homeomorphic to S1 itself." ?

Comment: When $S^1$ is parametrized by the polar angle $\phi$ then the map $\phi\mapsto2\phi$ is a homeomorphism from $S^1/(\pm1)$ to $S^1$.