# A question regarding the set of one-dimensional subspaces being the same as a circle.

Tags: algebraic-topology

My Topology book says that in $\Bbb{R^2}$, the set of all one-dimensional subspaces (or lines passing through the origin) is a circle.

[This stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169369/1-dim-subspace-sphere) says that this is because every subspace can be uniquely identified by the points at which it intersects the circle. I have the following questions:

1. If uniquely identifying each subspace by its intersection points is our purpose, then wouldn't a semicircle on the x-axis do as well?
2. It seems a set containing unique (symbolic) representations for each subspace is the *same* as the set of subspaces. Is this interpretation correct? In countable cases, would a set of the form $\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$ be the *same* as the set of subspaces?

Comment: This set is known as the 1-dimensional projective space $\mathbb{R}P^1$. Yes you are kind of right, you have the semicircle where both endpoints are actually again the same. As a hint: look closer on the map $S^1 \to \mathbb{R}P^1$. You can see then: your space is compact, this is a two sheeted covering, hence a local homeomorphism, it is a manifold with no boundary (classification of 1-manifolds tells you already that this is a circle) and more.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is basically answered by @DanValenzuela's comment; you *can* represent this collection of subspaces as a semicircle, provided you identify the two endpoints of the semicircle (since they intersect the same linear subspace). However, until you place a topology on the collection $X$ of linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we cannot quite say $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^1$; we've only determined a bijection of sets.

As for your second question, one does not *literally* mean that the two sets are the same. When working with one space (such as the collection of linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$), we often think in terms of a different, more convenient set (such as their intersection points with $S^1$, or $\mathbb{RP}^1$).  For example, we refer to angles as "$\pi/3$" or "$7\pi/2$" or "$513^\circ$". Even though we are picturing geometric angles, we refer to them as elements of $\mathbb{R}$ for convenience.

In the above cases, we are taking advantage of *set bijections*. But there are other -- sometimes stronger -- forms of equivalence that are useful in other areas of math. For example, topologists will commonly call an object a "sphere" or a "ball", when they really mean that the space is *homeomorphic* to a sphere or a ball.  In the case of $X$ above, the most natural topology to put on $X$ is the one that makes it homeomorphic to $\mathbb{RP}^1$. So a topologist would say that $X$ and $\mathbb{RP}^1$ are the same. The language all depends on the category of mathematical objects you're using and the notion of equivalence in that category.